# Determine the basis for the following subspace in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> The plane $x - y = 0$

This seems very easy, but I will do it in case I'm barking up the wrong tree. Also, if there is a more efficient way to do it please tell me.

$y$ is a free variable so let it equal $r$
$x = y = r$
therefore,
$$v = \begin{bmatrix}
r \\
r \\
\end{bmatrix} = r\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore, the dimension is 1, and the basis vector is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Ok so going further on what @StackTD said
$x - y + (0)z = 0$
$z = r$
$y = s$
$x = s - (0)r = s$
Therefore
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} s \\ s \\ r \\ \end{bmatrix}
= s\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + 
r \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} 
$$

I know this is correct because @Fred said.

Comment: If this is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the vectors should have 3 components...

Comment: Oh, yes you are correct. hhmmm. Now I know why it was so easy...it was wrong.

Comment: If it's a plane, it had better have dimension 2, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore, the dimension is 1, and the basis vector is

But you can expect a plane to be two-dimensional, right?

**Hint**: you're forgetting the third (and also free) variable $z$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Am going with @StackTD for gently pushing me to the answer in a timely manner. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Thanks & you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If $\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{bmatrix}$ is in the plane , then $x=y$ and $z$ is arbitrary, hence a bsis is given by

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thanks for your help again @Fred.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a close look at our plane $$P:=\{\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \vert x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}, x-y=0\}=\{\begin{pmatrix} y\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \vert y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}\\
=\{y\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+z\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\vert y,z \in \mathbb{R} \}=<\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}>_{\mathbb{R}}$$ where $<\cdot , \cdot>_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the span of the two vectors in $\mathbb{R}$. Because of the definition of generating set and span, $\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$ is a generating set for $P$. Furthermore the two vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent. Thus $\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$ is a set of linearly independet vectors which are a generating set for $P$ and therefore a basis for $P$.

Comment: Nice work @H.Vogel. I will keep an eye out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Close,  but no cigar.  You're in $\mathbb R^3$, so you need $3$ coordinates. ..  Secondly,  a plane is $2$ -dimensional.   So, let $y=x $ as you have done;  and then your  $z $ is actually free...  You get $ \{(x,x,z):x,z\in \mathbb R\}$.  Thus your basis is $\{(1,1,0), (0,0,1)\} $...

Comment: I want the cigar.

Comment: Cheers @ChrisCuster

Comment: Cheers @Bucephalus